# opencv Mat 16 bits from QVector

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

It's perhaps a very basic question. 
I want to build a cv::Mat from QVector. It works well in 8 bits Mat.

```
QVector<uchar> vector;
vector<<1<<289<<3000<<7<<2<<255<<266<<288;
Mat testMat(2,4,CV_8UC1,vector.data());
```

output:

```
[  1,  33, 184,   7;
   2, 255,  10,  32]
```

But when i use 16 bits Mat.

```
QVector<uint> vector;
vector<<1<<289<<3000<<7<<2<<255<<266<<288; 
Mat testMat(2,4,CV_16UC1,vector.data());
```

The result becomes:

```
[1, 0, 289, 0;
 3000, 0, 7, 0]
```

My question is why this happened and how to show without these 0.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CV_16UC1` has underlying type `unsigned short`, but not `uint`. Problem caused by different size of these types. Define your vector as `QVector<unsigned short> vector;`. This should fix the problem:

```
QVector<unsigned short> vector;
vector<<1<<289<<3000<<7<<2<<255<<266<<288; 
Mat testMat(2,4,CV_16UC1,vector.data());
```